# filezilla not connecting to a specific server but connecting to other

Tags: networking, ftp, cpanel, filezilla, server

I am using filezilla as my ftp client and I was successfully using it. But now filezilla is not connecting with one of my server. But it connects to other servers.

So I was confused and I thought the server may down. But when I checked in downorisitjustme.com the server appears to be online. Don't know what is going on. Can you guys please help me on it?

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's off-topic here.

Comment: Sorry to bother you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please check your FTP services status and try to stop firewall on your server, may be due to firewall you are unable to connect FTP server.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was a problem with my hosting side. They blocked my IP, may be because of a number  of unsuccessful login attempt. And it got solved. Thanks guys.